# It is possible to display the windows context menu for multiple files using DisplayContextMenu form JEDI JCL library?

Tags: delphi, contextmenu, jedi-code-library

It is possible to display the windows context menu for multiple files using `DisplayContextMenu` form [JEDI JCL library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/files/JCL%20Releases/JCL%202.6%20Build%205178/) ?

This is the code:

```
function DisplayContextMenu(const Handle: THandle; const FileName: string;
  Pos: TPoint): Boolean;
var
  ItemIdList: PItemIdList;
  Folder: IShellFolder;
begin
  Result := False;
  ItemIdList := PathToPidlBind(FileName, Folder);
  if ItemIdList <> nil then
  begin
    Result := DisplayContextMenuPidl(Handle, Folder, ItemIdList, Pos);
    PidlFree(ItemIdList);
  end;
end;

function DisplayContextMenuPidl(const Handle: THandle; const Folder: IShellFolder;
  Item: PItemIdList; Pos: TPoint): Boolean;
var
  Cmd: Cardinal;
  ContextMenu: IContextMenu;
  ContextMenu2: IContextMenu2;
  Menu: HMENU;
  CommandInfo: TCMInvokeCommandInfo;
  CallbackWindow: THandle;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (Item = nil) or (Folder = nil) then
    Exit;
  Folder.GetUIObjectOf(Handle, 1, Item, IID_IContextMenu, nil,
    Pointer(ContextMenu));
  if ContextMenu <> nil then
  begin
    Menu := CreatePopupMenu;
    if Menu <> 0 then
    begin
      if Succeeded(ContextMenu.QueryContextMenu(Menu, 0, 1, $7FFF, CMF_EXPLORE)) then
      begin
        CallbackWindow := 0;
        if Succeeded(ContextMenu.QueryInterface(IContextMenu2, ContextMenu2)) then
        begin
          CallbackWindow := CreateMenuCallbackWnd(ContextMenu2);
        end;
        ClientToScreen(Handle, Pos);
        Cmd := Cardinal(TrackPopupMenu(Menu, TPM_LEFTALIGN or TPM_LEFTBUTTON or
          TPM_RIGHTBUTTON or TPM_RETURNCMD, Pos.X, Pos.Y, 0, CallbackWindow, nil));
        if Cmd <> 0 then
        begin
          ResetMemory(CommandInfo, SizeOf(CommandInfo));
          CommandInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TCMInvokeCommandInfo);
          CommandInfo.hwnd := Handle;
          CommandInfo.lpVerb := MakeIntResourceA(Cmd - 1);
          CommandInfo.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
          Result := Succeeded(ContextMenu.InvokeCommand(CommandInfo));
        end;
        if CallbackWindow <> 0 then
          DestroyWindow(CallbackWindow);
      end;
      DestroyMenu(Menu);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The `GetUIObjectOf` method takes an array of `PItemIDList`s (its translation is crippled at least in Delphi XE3). So you need to build an array of `PItemIDList`s and pass it to the `GetUIObjectOf` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the context menu of several items, you must modify the code a little bit.

First you must allocate an array of PItemIDList and fill each element of the array and finally pass to the  `GetUIObjectOf` method the array with the number of elements.

Try this sample

```
uses
  JclShell,
  ShlObj;

function MenuCallback(Wnd: THandle; Msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  ContextMenu2: IContextMenu2;
begin
  case Msg of
    WM_CREATE:
      begin
        ContextMenu2 := IContextMenu2(PCreateStruct(lParam).lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtr(Wnd, GWLP_USERDATA, LONG_PTR(ContextMenu2));
        Result := DefWindowProc(Wnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
      end;
    WM_INITMENUPOPUP:
      begin
        ContextMenu2 := IContextMenu2(GetWindowLongPtr(Wnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
        ContextMenu2.HandleMenuMsg(Msg, wParam, lParam);
        Result := 0;
      end;
    WM_DRAWITEM, WM_MEASUREITEM:
      begin
        ContextMenu2 := IContextMenu2(GetWindowLongPtr(Wnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
        ContextMenu2.HandleMenuMsg(Msg, wParam, lParam);
        Result := 1;
      end;
  else
    Result := DefWindowProc(Wnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;

function CreateMenuCallbackWnd(const ContextMenu: IContextMenu2): THandle;
const
  IcmCallbackWnd = 'ICMCALLBACKWND';
var
  WndClass: TWndClass;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@WndClass, SizeOf(WndClass));
  WndClass.lpszClassName := PChar(IcmCallbackWnd);
  WndClass.lpfnWndProc := @MenuCallback;
  WndClass.hInstance := HInstance;
  Winapi.Windows.RegisterClass(WndClass);
  Result := CreateWindow(IcmCallbackWnd, IcmCallbackWnd, WS_POPUPWINDOW, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HInstance, Pointer(ContextMenu));
end;

type
  PArrayOfPItemIDList = ^TArrayOfPItemIDList;
  TArrayOfPItemIDList = array[0..0] of PItemIDList;

function DisplayContextMenuPidl(const Handle: THandle; const Folder: IShellFolder;
  Item: PArrayOfPItemIDList; ItemsCount :Integer; Pos: TPoint): Boolean;
var
  Cmd: Cardinal;
  ContextMenu: IContextMenu;
  ContextMenu2: IContextMenu2;
  Menu: HMENU;
  CommandInfo: TCMInvokeCommandInfo;
  CallbackWindow: THandle;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (Item = nil) or (Folder = nil) then
    Exit;
  //pass the number of elements oif the array (ItemsCount)
  Folder.GetUIObjectOf(Handle, ItemsCount, Item[0], IID_IContextMenu, nil,
    Pointer(ContextMenu));
  if ContextMenu <> nil then
  begin
    Menu := CreatePopupMenu;
    if Menu <> 0 then
    begin
      if Succeeded(ContextMenu.QueryContextMenu(Menu, 0, 1, $7FFF, CMF_EXPLORE)) then
      begin
        CallbackWindow := 0;
        if Succeeded(ContextMenu.QueryInterface(IContextMenu2, ContextMenu2)) then
        begin
          CallbackWindow := CreateMenuCallbackWnd(ContextMenu2);
        end;
        ClientToScreen(Handle, Pos);
        Cmd := Cardinal(TrackPopupMenu(Menu, TPM_LEFTALIGN or TPM_LEFTBUTTON or
          TPM_RIGHTBUTTON or TPM_RETURNCMD, Pos.X, Pos.Y, 0, CallbackWindow, nil));
        if Cmd <> 0 then
        begin
          ZeroMemory(@CommandInfo, SizeOf(CommandInfo));
          CommandInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TCMInvokeCommandInfo);
          CommandInfo.hwnd := Handle;
          CommandInfo.lpVerb := MakeIntResourceA(Cmd - 1);
          CommandInfo.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
          Result := Succeeded(ContextMenu.InvokeCommand(CommandInfo));
        end;
        if CallbackWindow <> 0 then
          DestroyWindow(CallbackWindow);
      end;
      DestroyMenu(Menu);
    end;
  end;
end;

function DisplayContextMenu(const Handle: THandle; const  FileNames: array of string;  Pos: TPoint): Boolean;
var
  ItemIdList: PArrayOfPItemIDList;
  Folder: IShellFolder;
  ItemsCount : integer;

  procedure AllocItems;
  var
    i : integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to  ItemsCount- 1 do
      ItemIdList[i] := PathToPidlBind(FileNames[i], Folder);
  end;

  procedure ReleaseItems;
  var
    i : integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to  ItemsCount- 1 do
      PidlFree(ItemIdList[i]);
  end;

begin
  Result := False;
  ItemsCount := Length(FileNames);
  if ItemsCount>0 then
  begin
    //Allocate the array
    ItemIdList := AllocMem(SizeOf(PItemIDList) * ItemsCount);
    try
       AllocItems; //fill each item 
      try
        Result := DisplayContextMenuPidl(Handle, Folder, ItemIdList, ItemsCount, Pos);
      finally
        ReleaseItems; //release the items 
      end;
    finally
       FreeMem(ItemIdList); //release the array
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And use like so

```
 DisplayContextMenu(Handle, ['C:\Foo\Bar.txt', 'C:\Foo\Bar2.txt'], Point(0, 0));
```

Comment: E2010 Incompatible types: 'PItemIDList' and 'PArrayOfPItemIDList' <-- on call to `DisplayContextMenuPidl`

Comment: Try this sample http://pastebin.com/8nmiZbK3   (check the order of the units JclShell and ShlObj)

Comment: Now the `GetUIObjectOf` returns NIL :(

Comment: Yes, they exists. If I pass just one file the menu is shown.

Comment: Are the files located in the same folder?

Comment: It works ! I was doing it a little different. I've declared `Item` parameter of the `DisplayContextMenuPidl` as `PItemIDList` type and when I was calling the function I was passing ItemIDList[0]. However, I dont't understand why is not working in this way, because the address of the first array item is the same as the array itself... Strange.